# Is it safe to modify data in between fetchArray calls?

Tags: php, sqlite

I need to perform a search and replace on a column (`MY_COL`) on a table (`MY_TABLE`). Assume the `MY_COL` is encoded and cannot be modified using `REPLACE` or `UPDATE SET`.

Is it safe to modify rows in between `fetchArray` calls like in the example below?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ID, MY_COL FROM MY_TABLE');
$res = $stmt->execute();

while($row = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    $new_col = $row['MY_COL'];
    //modify new_col after decoding then re-encode it

    $stmt2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_COL=:new_col WHERE ID=:id');
    $stmt2->bindParam(':new_col', $new_col);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':id', $row['ID']);
    $stmt2->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite computes result rows on demand, so depending on how the tables scan happens to be implemented, the read cursor might lose its exact position in the table, and skip over some row, or read it twice.

You could read all values into a list before doing the updates.

Alternatively, [register a user-defined function](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.createfunction.php) so that you can update all rows at once:

```
$db->exec('UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = MyFunction(MyCol)');
```